# How to write tests for classes relying on the operating system

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing

I have written a class that enumerates over the operating system's physical displays, retrieving their information and capabilities. I actually would like to test that this class works appropriately and embrace (unit) tests in general.

However, I have no idea how I would go about testing this class. Leaving the implementation details aside, it's basically defined as so:

```
class VideoMode {
public:
    int64 width;
    int64 height;
    std::vector<int64> frequencies;
}

class Display {
protected:
    std::vector<VideoMode> modes_;
    std::string display_name_;
    std::string adapter_name_;
    bool primary_;

public:
    Display(char* osDevName, char* osAdapterDevName);

    // typical getters
}
```

How would I go about testing something that is so deeply integrated and dependent on the OS, and the physically attached hardware. I understand that writing an unit test for a class like this is difficult, so what alternatives do I have?

Comment: Not everything can be unit tested. If there are too many external dependencies (that you cannot stub out in a sensible  way) you have to settle for other tests - like black-box tests, integration tests, manual tests. Sad but true.. sometimes trying to perfect tests for "all-the-things" is admirable but just not worth the return on investment - remember to be realistic and pragmatic.

Comment: I understand that, I'll make a small change to my question.

Comment: What you would merely test is that classes against `char* osDevName`and `char* osAdapterDevName` and the framework behind. I'd try to provide a mockup for `osAdapterDev` whatever that leads to, and check if all functions are called as expected.

Comment: What are `typical getters` and why do you need them???

Comment: @SergeyA Presumably they are `std::string const& adapter_name() { return adapter_name_; }`, etc., and they are needed because the class and its children can change the variables (so you can’t make them `const`) but people using the class cannot, and/or because you don’t want to expose the implementation detail that you use a `std::vector` for the video modes and you just want to return an iterator without the API changing if you switch to a different container.

Comment: @DanielH Exactly as you said it, yes.

Comment: @DanielH, how exactly can the class change values of `adapater_name_` and `display_name_` after it has been constructed? Does it support dynamic reconfiguring based on changed environment? If not, than the argument is moot. As for `vector`, and returning iterator to it, this is not the brightest idea. Unless you **really** provide majority of vector querying API (size, forward/reverse iterators, etc) but that goes beyond 'normal getter'. Also, providing `std::vector<>::iterator` as part of your API isn't much different than providing `std::vector<>` as if you think about it. It is worse.

Comment: Regardless of what the getters are for, and how the class is derived from is irrelevant to the scope of this question.

Comment: @SergeyA How should I know what can be changed at runtime; I’m not writing the class? And it is perfectly reasonable to say `using iterator = std::vector<VideoMode>::iterator;` in a container which uses `vector` as an internal type to store data. Even `std::array` has `typedef value_type*                             iterator;` on my machine, and as long as nobody looks at the implementation details and notices that `Display::iterator` is a `std::vector<VideoMode>::iterator`, it won’t cause a problem. Just because getters and setters are more useful in Java doesn’t mean they’re useless in C++.

Comment: @DanielH, I say it loud and proud - trivial setters and getters are useless and pure evil.

Comment: @SergeyA How should you get a vector’s size or capacity, then? I think `std::vector::size()` and `std::vector::capacity` can be trivial (depending on implementation details; a vector could store them or it could store pointers for them), but I can’t think of a way to avoid having them.

Comment: @DanielH, you misunderstand trivial setter/getter. std::vector::size() is not considered trivial, because it a. not fixed after object construction (can't be const member) b. Can't be modified directly and is part of class invariant. In given example, since I am pretty sure OP doesn't reread the configuration, those members should have made const and given undeterred access as public members.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, [a `const` public member is better than a public getter of a non-`const` non-public member when the member doesn’t change internally](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c131-avoid-trivial-getters-and-setters). But you’re making assumptions that aren’t in the question about what the class does. There could very well be a derived class we don’t see which lets you change the video mode of a display or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unit-test your class, not the os/external library functions.

You may add a facade layer which allows to mock those method. (That layer would not be unit tested by your UTs).

Something like:

```
class IOsVideoModeRetriever
{
public:
     virtual ~IOsVideoModeRetriever() = default;
     virtual std::vector<VideoMode> RetrieveVideoModes(/*...*/) = 0;
     // ...
};

// CLass with implementation of OS specific functions
class OsVideoModeRetriever : public IOsVideoModeRetriever
{
public:
     std::vector<VideoMode> RetrieveVideoModes(/*...*/) override;
     // ...
};

// Class for UT
class OsVideoModeRetrieverMock : public IOsVideoModeRetriever
{
public:
     MOCK(RetrieveVideoModes(/*...*/)); // Mock according to your framework
     // ...
};
```

And your other class use it something like:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    explicit Foo(IOsVideoModeRetriever&);

private:
    IOsVideoModeRetriever& mOsVideoModeRetriever; // Or use `shared_ptr`
                                                  // depending of life time guaranty
};
```

Now you can test `Foo`.

You indeed would have problems if the os specific functions doesn't behave as you expected (Format of result, limitation to handle, edge case, ...), that should be limited to implementation part and not the interface.

Answer (score 1):

First step: don't unit test not the interface with the OS, but the rest of the code.  There is some code there; not much, but some.

Create an even lower API that your nice C++ interface talks to; it mimics a C style API your OS probably provides, even if it is a C++ class.

Like

```
struct OSDisplayInterface {
  virtual ~OSDisplayInterface() {}
  virtual std::size_t GetDisplayName( char const* name, char const* adapter, char* name, std::size_t name_buf_len ) = 0;
  virtual bool IsDisplayPrimary( char const* name, char const* adapter ) = 0;
  virtual bool GetVideoModeCount( char const* name, char const* adapter, std::size_t* mode_count ) = 0;
  struct video_mode {
    int64 width, height, frequency;
  };
  virtual bool GetVideoMode( char const* name, char const* adapter, std::size_t n, video_mode* mode ) = 0;
};
```

Or something that matches your lower level API as directly as you can.  The idea is that this code should only fail in the *real* case if the OS's API fails.

Then test your C++ code *against that*, with fake OS video mode sets.

---

If you want to go further, this is basically outside of unit tests, but you can test either the above "OS display interface" or directly test your class against the OS.

To do this, however, you'll need a bunch of different hardware configurations.

Start with a farm of test machines you can remote-deploy code to and get results back.

Deploy your code, isolated from the rest of your code base, to those machines.

Each machine has an identifier on it.

Build a machine-identifier to test-results table.

Test against that.  Ensure that when run on system "bob37", you get the right set of resolutions and the like.

Then, when an OS upgrade hits and the API is deprecated, you get an immediate red flag.  (Of course, you also get red flags when a new driver is patched that gives new frequencies)

Unit test harness looks up the machine identifier, runs your code, and confirms the test results match.

Automate the deployment of the code to said machines so you can run the test on dozens of hardware platforms on a code change.

This is at best at the border of "unit testing".  But you could imagine being in the middle of porting the OS-interface code to a new OS, environment or hardware, and running into problems that this would catch.